# Logical and Physical Models in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, domain-driven-design

Since Rails coupled domains models and persistence models together (ActiveRecord), I was looking for a more "Domain-driven design" approach on Rails.

I found this book, [Enterprise Rails](http://oreilly.com/catalog/9780596515201), that suggests separating the logical model (domain) and physical model (persistence). More here:
http://pt.scribd.com/doc/7905929/Physical-Models-and-Logical-Models-in-Rails

It looks good to me, but I'm afraid I going to far against some Rails conventions. What will it break? The book is almost 3 years old, so is there a better way of doing it in Rails 3?

Context: Rails 3.0, and I'm already using modules to separate the model's "concerns".

Tks!

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what problem the separation of "Logical" and "Physical" models is trying to solve, to be honest. It's certainly not conventional rails.

If you wanted to have different names for the model attributes vs database columns (for whatever reason) you could use virtual attributes and a before_save filter to assign values to the actual, DB-backed attributes).

Comment: Logical is the domain model, where it should be "pure" OO and Physical is where you persist your data/state. There are more information about this idea on the link above.

Comment: I had a quick look at your link. I can see the appeal from a purist point of view, but I'm not sure what the practical and pragmatic benefits are. The whole point of ActiveRecord (and RoR to some extent) is to tie the in-memory objects to the database objects very closely. If you're going to learn RoR, you'll probably find it a lot easier to stick to the conventions!

Comment: @Frankie I disagree its true Rails is based around the ActiveRecord pattern and promotes aspects of model driven design "out of the box". However, Rails is also modular the framework is designed to be extended and to allow you to  "drop in" alternative code, for example template engines such as haml.....

Comment: .... If someone wants to use the Rails presenter pattern or presenter/constructor pattern or  logical/physical model pattern or full blown domain driven development and its various object types the framework should should still be open to them, which it is. I am all for projects that can provided any of the above and they should be supported by communities. DDD would actually benefit large complex projects.

Comment: that should read presenter/conductor pattern